# "Transparent" Unicode input from keyboard

Tags: linux, keyboard, unicode

How can I enter Unicode characters from my keyboard?

I'm aware of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, hex, <kbd>Return</kbd> method of entering an arbitrary Unicode character provided by (I think) IBus, but this causes a prompt (an underlined "u") to appear, and you can see the hex numerals as you type them. I want a method that does not cause anything to appear except for the final character.

I want this because I have a programmable keyboard that I want to enter certain Unicode characters from. Currently, for example, I can press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to type a Greek letter delta (Δ), but for a fraction of a second as it's being typed, I can see `394` (the Unicode codepoint for Δ) gradually appear, and then be erased, which is kind of ugly.

I'd like a solution that works system-wide (e.g., not tied to certain apps), if possible.

Comment: You will need to provide more information about just where and when this input is happening than just "linux" (unfortunately). You can [edit] your question.

Comment: @MichaelHomer I don't want to be more specific than "linux", as I don't want a solution that is tied to certain apps only (if possible). An ideal solution would work on any distribution of linux, possibly with some extra software installed. I've edited my post to make this explicit.

Comment: It probably depends on something. Some softwares like `st` or `rofi` don't have the `ctrl+shift+u` feature.

The `u394` isn't visible for me by default (using Ubuntu, I3WM, Xorg) on any compatible software (I tried with `chromium`, `gedit` and `guake`), but if I run `ibus-daemon`, I see `u394` underlined on every compatible software. So, one solution is to kill `ibus-daemon`, assuming you don't need it for something else.

Comment: @ewen-goisot Interesting. I'll look into that. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found simply using UIM instead of IBus does what I want. UIM supports <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> like IBus, but it doesn't have an interactive prompt.